Azure Functions crashes with ModuleNotFoundError when built with Azure DevOps pipeline, but runs fine when manually deploy
I have Python 3.9 code and an Azure DevOps pipeline where it builds and deploy the code to Azure Functions.
The pipeline has been working fine for the past several weeks (it's new) and there was no deployment recently until I had to fix a few lines of code, then I pushed to Azure Repo which triggers the pipeline. But this time the Function crashed when triggered; this is the error message:

Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'holidays'. Cannot
find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing
module.

This is my requirements.txt file, which clearly states the holidays module version.
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
azure-identity==1.14.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-storage-blob==12.17.0
dotmap==1.3.30
holidays==0.32
json5==0.9.14
numpy==1.25.2
pandas==2.1.0
pyodbc==4.0.39
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests_oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlalchemy==2.0.20

If I deploy from VS Code using Azure Functions extension, the code runs fine without any error, so I'm suspecting that the DevOps pipeline is acting weird (despite nobody changed anything on the YAML file)
This is my azure-pipelines.yml file
trigger:
  - main
  
variables:
  azureSubscription: '<REDACTED>'
  functionAppName: <REDACTED>
  functionAppProjectPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/
  pythonVersion: '3.9'
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build Stage
  jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImage)
      
      steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          inputs:
            versionSpec: $(pythonVersion)

        - bash: |
            pip install -r requirements.txt
          workingDirectory: $(functionAppProjectPath)
          displayName: 'Install dependencies'

        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          displayName: 'Archive files'
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: $(functionAppProjectPath)
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: zip
            archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            replaceExistingArchive: true

        - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          artifact: drop
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy Stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      environment: <REDACTED>
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImage)
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
                displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
                inputs:
                  appType: functionAppLinux
                  appName: $(functionAppName)
                  azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                  package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

I don't know what's wrong here. Hoping someone could point the problem out. Thanks.

In order to resolve ModuleNotFound error make sure you use the step below correctly in your Azure Devops yaml pipeline:-
- bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

Make sure you are selecting correct Branch that includes your Function code for your Pipeline:-

Azure Repository:-

Complete yaml pipeline code for Durable Function:-
trigger:
- master

variables:
  azureSubscription: '7bxxxxxxxxb50eee'

  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc8'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.9 

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

My requirements.txt:-
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
azure-identity==1.14.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.7.0
azure-storage-blob==12.17.0
dotmap==1.3.30
holidays==0.32
json5==0.9.14
numpy==1.25.2
pandas==2.1.0
pyodbc==4.0.39
pytz==2023.3.post1
requests_oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlalchemy==2.0.20

Sample Durable Function code:-
import logging
import json

from azure.durable_functions import DurableOrchestrationContext, Orchestrator
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Orchestrator Function
def orchestrator_function(context: DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity('HelloSecret', "Tokyo")
    result2 = yield context.call_activity('HelloBlob', "Seattle")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity('HelloData', "London")
    return [result1, result2, result3]

main = Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)

# Activity Function to Read Secret
def hello_secret_activity(name: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Reading secret for: {name}")

    # Initialize the DefaultAzureCredential
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    # Access a secret from Azure Key Vault
    key_vault_url = "https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/"
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)
    secret_name = "<your-secret-name>"
    secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name)
    
    return f"Secret for {name}: {secret.value}"

# Activity Function to List Blobs
def hello_blob_activity(name: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Listing blobs for: {name}")

    # Initialize the DefaultAzureCredential
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    # Access Azure Blob Storage
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credential)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("your-container-name")
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    blob_names = [blob.name for blob in blob_list]
    
    return f"Blobs for {name}: {blob_names}"

# Activity Function to Perform Data Processing
def hello_data_activity(name: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Performing data processing for: {name}")

    # Example usage of pandas and numpy
    data = {
        'A': np.random.rand(10),
        'B': np.random.rand(10),
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_summary = df.describe().to_json()
    
    return f"Data summary for {name}: {df_summary}"

# HTTP Trigger to Start the Orchestration
async def http_start(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.", status_code=202)

Sample Http Trigger code:-
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from dotmap import DotMap
import holidays
import json5
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import pytz
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Initialize the DefaultAzureCredential
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    
    # Access a secret from Azure Key Vault
    key_vault_url = "https://siliconkeyvault9.vault.azure.net/"
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)
    secret_name = "secret3"
    secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name)
    logging.info(f"Secret: {secret.value}")

    # Access Azure Blob Storage
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://siliconstrg8.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credential)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("your-container-name")
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    blob_names = [blob.name for blob in blob_list]
    logging.info(f"Blobs in container: {blob_names}")

    # Example usage of pandas and numpy
    data = {
        'A': np.random.rand(10),
        'B': np.random.rand(10),
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_summary = df.describe().to_json()
    
    # Example usage of holidays
    us_holidays = holidays.US(years=2024)
    holidays_list = [str(date) for date in us_holidays]

    response = {
        "secret_value": secret.value,
        "blobs": blob_names,
        "data_summary": json5.loads(df_summary),
        "holidays": holidays_list
    }

    return func.HttpResponse(json5.dumps(response), mimetype="application/json")

Sample yaml code for Http Trigger code:-
trigger:
- main

variables:
  azureSubscription: '4d3e6xxxxxxf22707ba'

  functionAppName: 'siliconfuncapp'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.9'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.9 
    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

Output:-
For Durable Function:-
holidays package is installed correctly:-


For Http Trigger:-
holidays package is installed correctly:-



Modifying the pip install line like yours fixed the issue, thanks for providing such a detailed answer!

I'm using the similar yaml to SiddheshDesai and it works fine. If you still have the same error after trying pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt, try the steps below to narrow down the issue.

Download the artifact from the pipeline. ZIP deploy your function using Azure CLI az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path>.
If there is the same error in your function, the issue would be related to your artifact. Check the debug log when running pip install and see if holidays is installed like:

Collecting holidays==0.32
  Downloading holidays-0.32-py3-none-any.whl (754 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 754.4/754.4 KB 30.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00


If you can't see holidays in the log, try to run pip install holidays==0.32 in your pipeline and check if it works.


I first thought that the holidays module wasn't installed as well so I checked the pipeline log but it was shown that the module got installed along with other modules. Fixing the pip install line as provided by SiddheshDesai fixed the issue for me. I assume the install directory was wrong.
